# How does the Blender User search for previous instance in the text editor window?

Tags: text-object

What are the keystrokes?

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html

Find the next instance .... from the documentation

Find & Set Selection Ctrl-G
Finds the next instance of the selected text.

---

Thanks

Comment: AFAICT there is no shortcut nor any operator to search for previous element

Comment: As @Gorgious said, there's no going back.  The best you can do is enable wrap and go forward until you wrap around.

Comment: Might be worth a new post in Right Click Select, looks like a feature that should be pretty straightforward to implement and a good addition to the text editor